# Convert multiline log to single line

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have multiline log file and I want to convert it to single line log.

Multiline example:

```
6/13/2015 12:00:47 AM - {   562} START Web 
6/13/2015 12:00:47 AM - Requested Web connection from 123.125.71.103 [123.125.71.103], ID=562 
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - {   563} START POP3 
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - Requested POP3 connection from 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37], ID=563 
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - (   563) USER test.mail@test.me 
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - POP3 connection with 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37] ended. ID=563 
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - {   563} END POP3
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - {   564} START POP3 
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - Requested POP3 connection from 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37], ID=564 
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - (   564) USER test.mail@test.me 
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - POP3 connection with 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37] ended. ID=564 
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - {   564} END POP3
6/13/2015 12:01:40 AM - Web connection with 123.125.71.103 [123.125.71.103] ended. ID=562 
6/13/2015 12:01:40 AM - {   562} END Web
```

For start I would like single line output like this, where I match same log IDs (for example "562").

```
6/13/2015 12:00:47 AM - {   562} START Web 6/13/2015 12:00:47 AM - Requested Web connection from 123.125.71.103 [123.125.71.103], ID=562 6/13/2015 12:01:40 AM - Web connection with 123.125.71.103 [123.125.71.103] ended. ID=562 6/13/2015 12:01:40 AM - {   562} END Web
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - {   563} START POP3 6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - Requested POP3 connection from 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37], ID=563 6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - (   563) USER test.mail@test.me  6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - POP3 connection with 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37] ended. ID=563  6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - {   563} END POP3
6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - {   564} START POP3 6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - Requested POP3 connection from 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37], ID=564 6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - (   564) USER test.mail@test.me  6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - POP3 connection with 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37] ended. ID=564  6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - {   564} END POP3
```

I have done following bash script which is not working as expected since it's merging all "POP3" or "Web" messages to single line and not sepparating them based on message ID.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

HOME=/var/tmp/test.txt

ID=`((awk '$6 ~/[0-9]\W/ {print $6}' $HOME | awk '{gsub (/)/, ""); print}' | awk '{gsub (/}/, ""); print}') && (awk '$11 ~/[0-9]/ {print $11}' $HOME | awk '{gsub ("ID=", ""); print}'))`


for ID in $HOME
do
        awk '!/Web/' $HOME | xargs >> final.txt
        awk '/Web/' $HOME | xargs >> final.txt
done
```

Any suggestion how I should create loop to merge only same IDs?

Comment: Are the aberrant brackets around the ID in `(   564) USER test.mail@test.me` an accidental typo?

Comment: Using the reserved variable `HOME` as a loop variable is a recipe for disaster.  Also, the `xargs` seems completely superfluous.  Everything could probably be converted into a single Awk script for much improved readability, performance, robustness, and correctness.

Comment: The UNIX shell is an environment from which to call UNIX tools with a language to let you sequence those calls, it is NOT a tool to manipulate text. The UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk - the whole solution should be just 1 awk script. And yes, overwriting the contents of `HOME` by using it as a variable name is a terrible idea! Get the books Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins and Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson.

Comment: NO, ( 564) USER test.mail@test.me is right information, not typo. I used variable HOME as example and know that I need to use different.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with an Awk script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f
{
    if($5 ~ /[{(]/) {
        split($6, b, /[)}]/)
        id = b[1]
    } else {
        split($NF, b, "=")
        id = b[2]
    }
    a[id] = a[id] FS $0
}
END 
{
    for(id in a)
        print a[id]
}
```

Run like:

```
$ awk -f script.awk logfile
 6/13/2015 12:00:47 AM - {   562} START Web  6/13/2015 12:00:47 AM - Requested Web connection from 123.125.71.103 [123.125.71.103], ID=562  6/13/2015 12:01:40 AM - Web connection with 123.125.71.103 [123.125.71.103] ended. ID=562  6/13/2015 12:01:40 AM - {   562} END Web
 6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - {   563} START POP3  6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - Requested POP3 connection from 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37], ID=563  6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - (   563) USER test.mail@test.me  6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - POP3 connection with 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37] ended. ID=563  6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - {   563} END POP3
 6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - {   564} START POP3  6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - Requested POP3 connection from 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37], ID=564  6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - (   564) USER test.mail@test.me  6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - POP3 connection with 10.127.251.37 [10.127.251.37] ended. ID=564  6/13/2015 12:01:24 AM - {   564} END POP3
```

The script checks the 5th field for `{` or `(` characters and splits the 6th or last fields accordingly to obtain the correct `id`.  Then, the id is used as a key in the array `a` to append the line (`$0`) to its corresponding value.  All elements of the array are then printed after every line has been processed.